# Regular Expression for OPTION value parse from Select tag

Tags: html, regex, go, html-parsing

What should be regex to OPTION

I am using this

```
<SELECT name="SELECT___F14CCNYCV___31".*?>\s*?(.+)?\s*?</SELECT>
```

But result is Blank .. I want to use this Regex in GoLang.

Html sample having New line and spaces

**HTML Sample**

```
<SELECT name="SELECT___F14CCNYCV___31" onChange="change_option('SELECT___F14CCNYCV___31',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<OPTION value="167" >0/3 months</OPTION>
<OPTION value="169" >3/6 months</OPTION>
<OPTION value="175" >6/9 months</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions is hard to impossible. Maybe using golang.org/x/net/html to parse the HTML would be a) easier and b) more robust?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/532430